# Need a to_csv array fix for python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm writing a code to be able to make a csv file from my dataFrame. The problem is that some columns in my dataFrame contain array value, so it wont make the csv file, it just giving me array error.

How do I get the first value of the array as a string? I tried using explode() but that i can only do once. Is there other kind of fix for this problem?

I have something like this:

```
newDf = df.select(col("customer").alias("c"), col("array1").alias("a1"), 
col("array2").alias("a2"), explode(col("array3".alias("a32))
```

Then I making a sql query to build up what i want:

```
newDf.createOrReplaceTempView("csvFileTable")

sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT c, a1, a2, a3 FROM csvFileTable")

display(sqlDF)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample df which you are trying to convert to csv

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have posted a sample now

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a DataFrame called `df` with a column `arrcol` which contains arrays.  You can replace every array in that column with the first element of the array like this:

```
df['arrcol'] = df['arrcol'].str[0]
```

You may be confused by this used of `str`.  It is more typically used to slice string columns, but it works equally well for other sliceable types like array and list.

Comment: When doing this, I only get this error: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What if you just print the part to the right of the `=`?